# Catalan numbers and gambler's ruin paths

Tags: partitioning, gambling

**Edit**  I've edited this question several times, and in the end I essentially answered my own question.  No need to answer it yourself.  I made it slightly less long and rambling, in case anyone else is reading.

In a lecture on catalan numbers for an analysis of algorithms course hosted on coursera (https://www.coursera.org/course/aofa), the professor states that the number of gambler's ruin paths containing N wins satisfies the recursion for the catalan numbers.  I agree with that statement but I think the justification he gives is incorrect.  Am I right or am I missing something?

The recursion is $$T_N = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}T_k \, T_{N-1-k}$$ for $N>1$, with $T_0 = 1$.  The first few values are $T_1 = 1$, $T_2 = 2$, $T_3 = 5$ and $T_4 = 14$.

A gambler's ruin path containing $N$ wins satisfies the following properties:  $X \geq 0$, $X(0) = 0$, $X(2*N) = 0$, and $X(t+1) - X(t) \in \{-1, 1\}$, where $X(t)$ is the gambler's wealth after $t$ plays.

Note that the path contains $2\,N$ plays, half of which are wins and half of which are losses, and that the gambler's wealth is zero at both ends.  Although the "true" length of the path is $2\,N$ plays, I'll refer to the win-length $N$ in order to be consistent with the lecture slides.

Here's the lecture slide:

[image: catalan numbers and gambler's ruin paths]

...and the professor's discussion of that slide:

> Here's another application [of the catalan numbers]:  the gambler's
>   ruin problem.  You start with 0 dollars and you make 1 dollar bets.  ...  The
>   gambler [you] will keep going until he has 0 dollars, makes a bet, and loses,
>   and the game is over.  **How many ways are there for the gambler to do
>   that with N wins in the sequence?**  ...  It satisfies the same
>   recurrence [the catalan number recurrence].  **The first time the
>   gambler gets back to zero, that happens after k** [I think he should have said k+1, see below] **wins, then
>   independently you have a gambler's ruin problem on k and on N-1-k and
>   it follows the same recurrence.**

I think that's almost correct but not quite.  You do want to focus on the first time the gambler returns to zero.  But you want to say that that happens after $k+1$ wins -- and, crucially, because of the constraint that the path with $k+1$ wins does not hit zero until its endpoint, there are only $T_k$ such paths.  Therefore the number of paths containing a total of $N$ wins, and first returning to zero after $k+1$ wins, with $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, N-1\}$, is $T_k \, T_{N-1-k}$.  Is that right?

The example below shows N=6 wins and 6 losses.  The path is split into a win, a subpath of win-length $k=3$ with $X(t) \geq 1$, followed a loss that brings us back to zero for the first time, then a subpath of win-length $N-k-1$ with $X(t) \geq 0$.  We must have $k \in \{0, 1, \ldots, N-1\}$; we can count all paths of win-length $N$ by partitioning over these $k$.

[image: example with 6 wins]

Comment: By using the term "length" synonymously with *number of wins,* you risk confusing readers (and perhaps even yourself).  Even so, there are problems in the argument and the slide. The key is to decompose the paths according to the *first* time $X$ returns to $0$.

Comment: I agree that it's confusing -- I'm using the same terminology as in the lecture, simply so that I can comment on his recusion using his notation for $T_N$, the number of paths with N wins.  I'll edit to point that out.